# Open-SSH in Windows 10: cannot copy files to junctions when ChrootDirectory is set in sshd_config

Tags: windows-10, ssh, symbolic-link, openssh, sftp

I want do use an Open SSH-Server in Windows 10 to allow users access by SFTP to certain folders, basically two Partitions called C:\ and D:\ on the system.

For that reaoson, I have created a directory c:\intepub\ftproot, with two junctions C (which redirects to C:\, like this: mklink /J C:\intepub\ftproot\C C:), and D (which redirects to D:), and set that folder in sshd_config as ChrootDirectory:

```
ChrootDirectory C:\inetpub\ftproot
```

My problem now is that this seems to work when a client connects, but I cannot transfer any data to it, or when data is transferred with Filezilla for example, the file is created, but with 0 byte in size. So to me the culprit seems to be the symbolic directory link, which Open-SSH seems not to support. Can anybody confirm this?

It works when I set something like this:

```
ChrootDirectory C:\
```

But this way, I do not get what I want, i.e. make two partitions C and D accessible to the user.

Another strange thing I noticed is, that when I do not set a ChrootDirectory at all, and navigate to a junction like /C/intepub/ftproot/C/somedir directly, everything works fine. So this seems to be related to setting a ChrootDirectory, but I do not know why.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am using a local Administrator account to login.

Comment: THanks Martin, here are the steps I did to reproduce, even on a new system: 1.) Stop Open SSH Services
2.) Create folder called Symlinks in C:\ Create another folder called temp in C:\. 
3.) mklink /J C:\Symlinks\C C:\ 
4.) In C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config: ChrootDirectory C:\Symlinks 
5.) Restart Open SSH Services
6.) In Filezilla, add new connection to localhost, SFTP, Username/Password of you Windows Administrator Account
7.) Navigate to sftp path /C/temp, try to copy some files there
8.) Filezilla will create the file with size 0KB, but finally fails to copy content

Comment: I thin Chroot is nessecary, at the moment, I assume that the problem may be related to the source file not being accessible, rather than the destination. I found some explanations that by default, only the user's home folder is accessible, but I am not really sure how this concept applies to Windows permissions, since most you find about this topic is Unix-related.

Comment: Thanks Martin, good hint. When I do not set the ChrootDirectory, I am taken to my Windows-Users homefolder, and when I navigate manually to /C/Symlinks/C/temp, I can copy any files there. So this is obviously really related to the ChrootDerectory-entry. But why?

Comment: Good. I do not have an answer to that. But you should edit your question to including your findings (the question title needs an update too).

Comment: I will do that Martin, my question to you would be: can you reproduce the behaviour? It seems totally unlogical to me that everything works without a ChrootDirectory option... Strange!

Comment: I didn't try test this.

Comment: No problem Martin, what is your opinion? Looks like a bug in the Windows-implementation of openssh, or what do you think? All the Windows releases on Github are marked as prerelease, so I wonder which builds does Microsoft use in the newer Windows10 versions where they also officially offer OpenSSH officially in "Apps and features", see here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Comment: I think it's worth reporting to them.